# Errors retrieving packages using pacman on Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux

I've got a new install of Arch on my Pi (as in, got a new image, wrote it to ye olde SD carde, popped it in Pi) and I'm trying to install some of the utilities I need in order to do the stuff I want.

When I run `pacman -S vim` from the root prompt, I get the following error (sorry, a picture was the best I could do):

[image]

I confirmed that I have a network connection via ethernet by wget-ing www.google.com. I'm relatively unfamiliar with Arch, let alone on RPi. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like pacman tries to download older versions of packages, which are no longer available. Run `pacman -Sy` to update local databases (`pacman -Syy` to force update). You can combine this with package installation: `pacman -Sy vim`.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you.